# Plot a line between two points across the plot edge, i.e. a wrapped edge, in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a simulated system where the arena as wrapped edges, i.e. it's torus. Meaning that an animal can exit the arena on one side, and comes back on the other side. When I then want to illustrate this process, I would want the lines between the different locations to reflect this, i.e. a straight line that exits the plot on one side and continues on the opposite side. Is there any nifty way out there to achieve/automate this?

Horrible R-MS Paint hack to illustrate the line going from [6,2] to [8,2] and across the edge to [2,4].

[image]

From a typical data frame looking something like:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(6,8,2), y = c(2,2,4))
with(df, plot(y~x, xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,10), ylab = "Y", xlab = "X"))
```

Comment: Nifty? I don't think so, it will take specific effort to make it seemingly "easy" for the user. I suspect it'll take a combination of the modulus operator (`%%`) and either line grouping or intermediate `NA` to not connect one side to the other. Think about running around a track, where set the lap indicates which lap and where on the loop you currently are. If you want to plot (say) speed over fractional lap, you might do `lap %% 1` to find where on the track without regards to laps.

Comment: When MrFlick said "reproducible", it suggests the ability for us to try it on our console. Since we have no data and no code, all we can do is draw with crayons on our laptop screens, then try to hide it with white-out (further munging our screens). Please read and heed his link, then edit your question with something we can test.

Comment: Sorry about lack of reproducible code, I have added some now, but beyond that I was completely stuck at this point. So there really isn't anything there to test yet...

Comment: What is it you are expecting to be able to do? You want to automate it, what would your "nifty" code look like?

Comment: Initially I was hoping something along the lines; "Yeah, some bright heads have done something similar [fill in blanks] which can be adjusted for this case",

But I understand that I might have come across as a case of please-solve-my-case-without-me-having-tried-anything-scenario, and apologise for that. After having gone through a "writer's block" for the last couple hours here, I now seem to have some traction on a function using simple slope-intercept relationships with a ton of 'ifelse()' -statements for adding and subtraction of intercepts if it crosses an edge.

Comment: ego_, you may have not tried anything, but my biggest concern is you cannot clearly describe what you want to show and/or how. For instance, you showed data that created this plot, but what data do you have that you need to melt somehow onto this axis? If you don't have data (don't know what it looks like), then this is a problem of *"I don't know what the data looks like or how to make it look like this, but I want something to look like this"* ... a bit **too vague** and unclear, especially for SO.